# CSS: four divs dynamically sharing height of a parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div in a grid with height of `29rem + 1fr`. In the div there are four children. First and third have a fixed height (both have the same height as their content that does not change), and second and fourth must have dynamical height because of their content.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="unplanned"> Index
    <div class= "header"> </div>
    <div class="filter_line">filter: line </div>
    <div class="filter_date">filter: date </div>
   <div class="table">table </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.unplanned {z-index: 1500;
  grid-area: unplanned;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 96vh;/*right now it's set as fixed height that does not work it there is less content in filter_line*/}
.fitler_line {display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3.3rem;
  margin-left: 2.9rem;}
.fitler_date {margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;}
.table {text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc( 100% - 32rem ); /*right now it's set as fixed height that does not work it there is less content in filter_line*/}
```

I have tried adding `height: auto` to  "filter_line" and "table" and it works to an extend. It fits all lines in "filter_line" but it cuts off the table without scroll. Flex will not work, because it messes with grid.

Is there an elegant solution in CSS or Sass that will fit all of "table" content without JS?

Comment: maybe it's enough when you set `min-height` instead of `height` for .unplanned?

Comment: If there is not height specified on .table the `height` or `min-height` of .unplanned change nothing and the `height` on the .table above is wrong.

Comment: can you provide a working example with a jsfiddle? where is the css of your header class ? how is the grid parent ? flex and grid can be use both together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lays in flex attribute. 
You can use flex for extending last div to available space. Very good tutorial for flex is [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). (Do read for further understanding)

The solution is described here:

```css
.parent {
  background-color:red;
  height:500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.first {
  background-color:blue;
  height:50px
}

.second {
  background-color:green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.third {
  background-color:yellow;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">bdjasbdajsbdajsbd
  das<br>
  das<br>
  das<br>
  d<br>
  asd<br>
  a</div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```